# C# scraping project Click event issue

Tags: c#, selenium

I am new to scraping in C#
I have built a small c# scraping project and tried to run.
I am going to add a click event because the drop-down list(which shows football match score for example:3-0) is opened after click event.
This is the html structure of the web-page:

```
<table class="matches date_matches grouped">
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="date_matches-16-53658" class="group-head expanded loaded" stage-value="1">
            <th colspan="5">
                <h3>
                    <span class="flag_16 left_16 france_16_left">France-Ligue 1</span>
                </h3>   
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            ...
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I am going to realize this function with selenium

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
...
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//table[@class='matches']/tbody/tr[@class='group-head']/th[1]/h3/span"));
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
...
```

But it is not working: error -> element not find
Also tried like this way:

```
var ele = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@class ='flag_16 left_16 france_16_left']"));
ele.Click();
```

it says: "element is not interactable"
I am confused I could not realize this click event on the mark.
Looking forward to a good solution on this problem.
Regards...

Comment: Make sure you check out HtmlAgilityPack and a packet sniffer like Wireshark or Telerik Fiddler.  You're doing this the hard way without these tools.

Comment: thanks! it is helpful to my development!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you click to open the drop down first. Then I usually wait until the element is displayed in the drop down and then click it. Also your xpath was fine in the ele version. I am not sure what the other values in the span are showing for the class name? I am assuming they are all unique? If not, try looking by name -

```
 //span[contains(text(), 'France-Ligue 1')]
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this:::  var ele = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[contains(text(), 'Africa - CAF Champions League')]")); ele.Click();
and then it says:OpenQA.Selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: 'element click intercepted: Element <span class="flag_16 left_16 africa_16_left">...</span> is not clickable at point (118, 883). Other element would receive the click: <iframe.....

Comment: ok two things. I see reference to an ifrane in your comment. If this drop down is in an iframe, you will need to switch to it, then do the click, then switch back to main.  If there is no iframe, what is probably happening is that the element is being clicked while it is still loading. I am not a fan of thread sleeps but add on in and see if it works. So click the drop down, thread.sleep(1000); then click the element in the list. If that works, you can create a better wait vs a sleep.